# Add a tag to favourite tag list

Tags: support, tag-watching

How to add a tag to my favourite tag list. I could search for a tag but don't know how to add that to my favourite tag list.

Answer (score 2):

On the homepage or the questions lists page, click on `Add a favorite tag` link in the sidebar:

[image: add a favorite]

If you *already* have favorite tags, see [the answer by Richard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196464/140505).

Answer (score 2):

You need to click "Add a favourite tag" on your home page

[image]

Or to add more tags after you've already added some then you need to click "edit"

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Go to the home page  of [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions), see the right side you can see the link to add favorite tags like below

[image]

On clicking that link, you can type your favorite tag and hit `Add` button.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Hover over the tag and click on the star:

[image]

Comment: Click the star again to add the tag to your ignored list.

Comment: I've been using SO for a while and I did not notice this (+1)